# plot curves that are described by a matrix in matlab

Tags: matrix, matlab-figure

I have a matrix, where the row is generated by `X = [0:0.01:10]` and the column is generated by `Y = [20:-0.01:5]` The numbers in the matrix are either 0, 1 or 9 which partitions the matrix in to 3 distinct regions. I want to generate a XYplot such that it draws the boundaries of these regions that are captured by the numbers in the matrix.

Is there a clever way of achieving this goal in matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) and specify the levels on which to draw contours. In your case you want to draw a line on the 1 and 9 values.

```
contour(X, Y, thematrix, [1, 9])
```

where `thematrix` is the name of your matrix.

Comment: You didn't say what your matrix's variable name was, use that instead of `thematrix`.

Comment: I set K = zeros(length(X),length(Y)), then I did some computation to eventually generates my K matrix with only 1,0, 9 in it, then I run this  contour(X,Y,K,[1,9]), it says The size of Y must match the size of Z or the number of rows of Z. It is weird, since I never define a variable called Z

Comment: You may need to plot the matrix transposed. Try using `K'` instead. Otherwise there is a problem with the size of your `K`